# Positioning element relative to an element from another RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout that has a series of titles and descriptions that need to be displayed beside each other in the form

```
Title:         Description
Another Title: Description that is long
               and goes on two lines
Short Title:   Description 3
```

It needs to have spacing like in the example above.
This would be easy if I could use 2 relative layouts (one for titles and the other for descriptions) then I could set the width of the title layout to wrap content to get the spacing. The problem with this is I cannot use android:layout_toRightOf="..." while referencing an id in another relative layout.

If anyone could help me find a solution to this or let me know if I am looking at this the wrong way then I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using nested linear layouts instead? This is the sort of case where most people use them. You could try a table, but with LinearLayouts I'd suggest one vertical layout with lots of horizontal layouts inside it, with the weights of the left and right TextViews set the same between the rows, so that the text on the right is lined up.

Comment: that is a nice idea, but since the text views for titles all have different lengths, so weights will not allow all descriptions to be lined up.

Comment: That is the problem the weights will solve - set all widths to fill_parent, then all weights to 1, and the division will always be halfway.